# TSQL to find Null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, join

I have the following tables:

Product

```
PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_NAME
1           SCREW1.20
2           SCREW1.23
3           SCREW2.5
4           SCREW3.10`
```

Sales

```
SALE_ID  PRODUCT_ID  YEAR   QUANTITY    PRICE
1        1           2019   14          1.64
2        2           2011   20          2.13
3        3           2018   22          2.29
4        4           2019   18          2.02
5        1           2016   13          2.42
6        2           2019   13          2.36
7        3           2013   20          2.38
8        4           2018   20          2.20
9        1           2010   23          1.69
10       2           2016   22          1.84
11       3           2015   12          1.88
12       4           2009   23          2.47
13       1           2019   14          1.57
14       2           2013   16          1.32
15       3           2016   17          1.66
16       4           2016   16          2.11
17       1           2009   13          2.33
18       2           2015   13          1.84
19       3           2016   12          1.73
20       4           2015   19          1.98
21       1           2018   22          2.17
22       2           2014   21          1.63
23       3           2009   19          1.85
24       4           2010   14          2.17
25       1           2014   13          2.09
26       2           2018   13          1.78
27       3           2011   20          1.34
28       4           2020   22          2.28
29       1           2013   16          1.96
30       2           2016   13          1.37
31       3           2010   21          1.53
32       4           2012   22          2.53
33       1           2019   18          2.57
34       2           2015   22          1.69
35       3           2020   12          2.18
36       4           2019   18          2.63
37       1           2011   21          2.05
38       2           2010   18          1.47
39       3           2012   15          2.37
40       4           2016   21          2.15
41       1           2017   20          1.28
42       2           2019   17          2.13
43       3           2017   14          2.27
44       4           2017   13          1.63
45       1           2009   23          1.89
46       2           2010   13          2.49
47       3           2020   12          2.19
48       4           2009   16          2.34
49       1           2018   13          2.37
50       2           2013   23          1.24
51       3           2011   21          1.58
52       4           2020   21          1.96
53       1           2014   14          1.53
54       2           2015   12          1.85
55       3           2014   13          1.23
56       4           2009   17          2.26
57       1           2017   22          2.41
58       2           2017   20          2.19
59       3           2016   13          1.47
60       4           2018   17          2.05
61       1           2020   15          2.22
62       2           2020   18          1.63
63       3           2016   15          2.67
64       4           2012   18          2.40
65       1           2018   17          2.16
66       2           2017   19          1.57
67       3           2014   23          1.82
68       4           2017   22          2.27
69       1           2019   16          2.65
70       2           2011   16          2.37
71       3           2014   20          1.53
72       4           2014   17          1.81
73       1           2009   23          1.40
74       2           2010   16          2.13
75       3           2013   20          2.27
76       4           2016   17          2.09
77       1           2013   19          2.30
78       2           2016   14          1.40
79       3           2012   12          1.75
80       4           2013   15          1.41
81       1           2015   21          2.30
82       2           2019   16          1.81
```

**I want to find for each year the products which do not have any sales at all**

So my train of thought is to find the distinct years for the sales, for each of these iterate for every product, for each product determine the sales: `sum(quantity * price)`.

The result would have lines like these

```
YEAR    PRODUCT_NAME   Sales
(...)
2011    SCREW3.10      NULL
2012    SCREW3.10      98.96 (<- this record should not appear)
(...)
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` the `products` tabe with the distinct years available in `sales`, and then bring the `sales` table with a `left join`. When the `left join` comes up empty, you know you have a product that was not sold on that particular year:

```
select p.*, y.year
from products p
cross join (select distinct year from sales) y
left join sales s on s.year = y.year and s.product_id = p.product_id
where s.sale_id is null
```

You can also express this with `not exists` instead of `left join ... where ... is null`:

```
select p.*, y.year
from products p
cross join (select distinct year from sales) y
where not exists (
    select 1 from sales s where s.year = y.year and s.product_id = p.product_id
)
```

Comment: Just made a little tweak `select p.*, y.year, QUANTITY * PRICE  AS Sales
from products p
cross join (select distinct year from sales) y
left join sales s on s.year = y.year and s.product_id = p.product_id` to check the Sales value. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH Sales_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT S.*
        FROM Sales AS S
),
Products_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME
        FROM Products
),Years
AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT  [Year]
        FROM Sales_CTE AS S
        GROUP BY [YEAR]
)
SELECT Y.[YEAR],P.PRODUCT_NAME
    FROM Years AS Y
    CROSS JOIN Products_CTE AS P
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                        FROM Sales_CTE AS S 
                        WHERE Y.YEAR=S.YEAR AND P.PRODUCT_ID=S.PRODUCT_ID)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75ff5f5bc3d79e348d92b5924af12bad